# Mongodb Nodejs driver aggregate query does not return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've Mongodb aggreage query which works fine in the RoboMongo shell and yeild me the correct results.

Robo Mongo Shell Query

```
db.getCollection('application-filters').aggregate(
{

      $match: { 


          "StatusName" : {$in:["Rejected","Expired"]}


}},
{
$group:{
    _id: "$StatusName", COUNT : { "$sum":1} 
}},
{
$project: {
    StatusName:1,
    Count : "$COUNT"
}
},
{
    $sort:{
        Count:-1
    }
}
)
```

I've copied and paste the same query and trying to execute with nodejs mongodb 2.2 driver. it gives me no result

Here is JavaScript code

```
module.exports = mPool => {
  return {
    getcountbyStatus (countstatusfilterParams) {
      console.log(countstatusfilterParams)
      return mPool.collection('application-filters').aggregate(
        {

          $match: {

            'StatusName': {$in: ['Rejected', 'Expired']}

          }},
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$StatusName', COUNT: {'$sum': 1}
          }},
        {
          $project: {
            StatusName: 1,
            Count: '$COUNT'
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            Count: -1
          }
        }
).toArray(function (err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(data)
  }
})
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      // do your query
]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      // do something
}
```

So in this case your Mongodb aggreage should be:

```
module.exports = mPool => {
  return {
    getcountbyStatus (countstatusfilterParams) {
      console.log(countstatusfilterParams)
      return mPool.collection('application-filters').aggregate([
        {

          $match: {

            'StatusName': {$in: ['Rejected', 'Expired']}

          }},
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$StatusName', COUNT: {$sum: 1}
          }},
        {
          $project: {
            StatusName: 1,
            Count: '$COUNT'
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            Count: -1
          }
        }
]).toArray(function (err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(data)
  }
})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No it still doesn't work. I'm still getting blank array.

Comment: I even tried to replicate the code based on this example http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/aggregation/ But still doesn't works